# Get global position of widget in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have an image located relative to the screen size with `RelativeLayout`. How can I get the global (/window) position of that image, so that I can detect if touch coordinates overlap the image?

this is my current implimentation:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

class mainApp(App):
    def build(slef):

        appRoot = FloatLayout()
        relPos = RelativeLayout()

        button = Image()
        relPos.pos_hint = {"right":1,"top":1.5}

        relPos.add_widget(button)

        #attempting to print the coordinates of the Image in the window
        print(relPos.to_parent(*button.pos))

        return relPos

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to use `to_parent` to get the position relative to the parent. However, I don't think it works `pos_hint`.

I've also tried using `AnchorLayout`, and have had similar issues

Note: while I know I can use the `window_size`, allong with a bit of math, I would like a more robust solution that can handle more complex situations

Comment: Does not `print(button.pos)` suffice? I believe pos attribute of a widget is always relative to the window

Comment: @JacobStrauss printing `print(button.pos)` results in `(0,0)`, regardless of where it is actually located by changing `relPos.pos_hint = {"right":1,"top":1.5}`

Comment: You cannot get positions inside the `build()` method, because the widgets have not yet been positioned. Try putting your `print()` in another method that you call using `Clock.schedule_once()`.